# How to join two HashMaps having same key and different values

Tags: hashmap

I have two hashmaps and I want to join both the maps where the keys are same and the values are different or same.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> h1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
HashMap<String, Integer> h2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
h1.put("A",1);
h1.put("B", 2);
h1.put("C",32);

h2.put("A",321);
h2.put("B", 4562);
```

I need to merge this map so that it looks like {A=[1,321],B=[32,4562],C=[32]}
If I am using Java 7 then how should I do it?

Comment: create a new hash map, loop over both and join them. I dont think we have api to merge them.

Comment: Create new HashMap<String, String> and add all elements of h1 to this new hashmap, then iterate h2 and check if key exists in new hashmap then retrieve the value and append the value from h2 to new hashmap.

I dont think we have any API for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap that takes in an array as the value.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> combined = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

Then write a for loop for the keys of each map

```
for(String key: mapA.keys()){
    if(!combined.keys().contains(key))
        combined.put(key, new List<Integer>());
    combined.get(key).put(mapA.get(key))
```